# How to change Wordpress Post Query variable in URL ("p")

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress have "p" variable in query string for showing post where id of post = p variable. Is there any way to change this var name? Or to add variable that will be doing the same thing? Im looking for a way to make wordpress recognize query like this:
wordpresssite.com/?id=123

Comment: Why would you want to change is ? what is the reason . ( Just curious )

Answer (score 3):

Those are just query vars , and `P?`simply  means `post` .
To  change it you can create a custom post type ([CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)).
Then, for example, if your custom post type name is : `"bulding"` , it will show as

```
?bulding=xx
```

Just as page shows as `page_id=` and attachment shows as `attachment=`  ( both are post types , but reserved and implemented as default )

That being said, I do not really understand why one would like to change it , and why is that disturbs , but I would sure like to hear that ..

Comment: I was asking, because I was moving old website to Wordpress, and trying to keep links look the same.